# grep specific number of consequtive lines that follow a pattern from a file

Tags: awk

Would it be posible to use awk to extract only 
consecutive lines that contain "A 0", "A 1", "A 2", "A 3", "A 4" and "A 5"
from a file that has a structure as below:

```
..........................................................................
LINE  6295  A 0  LESS L6179     214.617 184.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6296  A 1  LESS L6179     215.525 185.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6297  A 2  LESS L6179     215.265 186.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6298  A 3  LESS L6179     217.012 184.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6299  A 4  LESS L6179     217.659 185.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6300  A 5  LESS L6179     219.029 184.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L      
LINE  6316  A 0  LESS L6180     222.617 184.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6317  A 1  LESS L6180     223.525 185.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6320  A 4  LESS L6180     225.659 185.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6344  A 0  LESS L6222     158.617 192.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6345  A 1  LESS L6222     159.525 193.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6346  A 2  LESS L6222     159.265 194.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6347  A 3  LESS L6222     161.012 192.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6348  A 4  LESS L6222     161.659 193.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6349  A 5  LESS L6222     163.029 192.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L      
LINE  6367  A 2  LESS L6223     167.265 194.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6368  A 3  LESS L6223     169.012 192.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6369  A 4  LESS L6223     169.659 193.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6370  A 5  LESS L6223     171.029 192.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L    
..........................................................................
```

Something that would provide an output of this type:

```
LINE  6295  A 0  LESS L6179     214.617 184.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6296  A 1  LESS L6179     215.525 185.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6297  A 2  LESS L6179     215.265 186.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6298  A 3  LESS L6179     217.012 184.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6299  A 4  LESS L6179     217.659 185.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6300  A 5  LESS L6179     219.029 184.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L   
LINE  6344  A 0  LESS L6222     158.617 192.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6345  A 1  LESS L6222     159.525 193.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6346  A 2  LESS L6222     159.265 194.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6347  A 3  LESS L6222     161.012 192.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6348  A 4  LESS L6222     161.659 193.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L     
LINE  6349  A 5  LESS L6222     163.029 192.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L
```

Comment: anything is **possible**. Have you tried something that is almost-but-not-quite working? Show your attempt and where specifically you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`, since you can look at specific columns, rather than a more general `grep` how about checking that column 3 is "A" and column 4 cycles from 0 to 5? That would be

```
awk 'BEGIN{seek=0} $3=="A" && $4==seek {print; seek +=1; if (seek>5) seek=0}' file.txt
```

Comment: this will print first line even if you change the second line to `A0`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3=="A" && $4==s {A[s]=$0; s++; if (s<6) next;}
      s==6 {for(i=0; i in A; i++) print A[i]; s=0; next;}
      {s=0}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
LINE  6295  A 0  LESS L6179     214.617 184.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6296  A 1  LESS L6179     215.525 185.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6297  A 2  LESS L6179     215.265 186.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6298  A 3  LESS L6179     217.012 184.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6299  A 4  LESS L6179     217.659 185.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6300  A 5  LESS L6179     219.029 184.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6344  A 0  LESS L6222     158.617 192.380  50.086  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6345  A 1  LESS L6222     159.525 193.163  49.136  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6346  A 2  LESS L6222     159.265 194.663  49.269  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6347  A 3  LESS L6222     161.012 192.776  49.298  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6348  A 4  LESS L6222     161.659 193.089  50.654  1.00  0.00      L
LINE  6349  A 5  LESS L6222     163.029 192.429  50.766  1.00  0.00      L
```